# Openshift Perl dependencies not loading from .openshift/cpan.txt

Tags: perl, dependencies, openshift, cpan

I have reviewed the dependency documentation found here:
https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185484-Adding-dependencies-to-applications

And reviewed the information on .openshift/cpan.txt replacing deplist.txt found here:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/perl-overview.html#_template_repository_layout

I have attempted to use the following file in both locations

```
File::Slurp
File::Path
File::Basename
DBI
XML::Simple
Moose
```

However the build does not seem to recognize these dependencies. The build does not report errors, but the cpan modules are not available.

```
[myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com]\> perl -e "use File::Slurp" 
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

This is a php application with mySql and phpMyAdmin cartridges but I have not found any way to add a "Perl Cartridge" and I saw a post (can't find the link) that indicated it was not necessary as perl was available with all apps. I think I'm missing something somewhere, maybe a Perl cartridge or configuration file is necessary, or maybe headers other content needed in the cpan.txt file? The documentation indicates that the cpan.txt file should "look something like this" - but I could not find anything that gave a real file format spec.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the PHP cartridge, you will not be able to automatically install Perl modules using the above methods.  That only works on the Perl cartridge.  You can try sshing into your gear and running the "perl -MCPAN -e shell" manually, but you might not have write access to the ~/.cpan directory on your gear, so that may not work either.  If you can provide more information about what you are trying to do someone might have a suggested solution.

Comment: I have a php application, and one small but critical components of that application runs as a Perl script to generate some output. The Perl script requires the listed perl modules. I've tried running the cpan installs manually, but as you suspected I don't have the proper access. I would also be concerned that I would loose that type of configuration after a subsequent re-deploy of the app. Is there any way to add a Perl cartridge to my application?